# ESP32 watchdog errors when I need a loop to constantly stream data

Tags: esp32

My ESP32 is connected to an NRF24L01 chip where by it receives a stream of audio data.  I then relay this information via WiFi over to an MQTT broker.

Here's a few parts from my arduino IDE sketch code from my first attempt (I'll show the full code at end of question):

```cpp
void onReceiveRadio(void * param) {

  esp_task_wdt_add(nullptr);
  while(1)
  {    
    bool n = !whichBuff;
    if(!buffFull[n] && radio.available() )
    {   
      radio.read(&buffer[n][loadBufferN],buffSize);         // Read the payload from the radio
      loadBufferN++;
    }

    if(loadBufferN >= bucketTotal)
    {
      loadBufferN = 0;
      buffFull[n] = true;
      whichBuff = n;
    }
  }
}

void setup() {      
  Serial.begin(115200);   // Enable Arduino serial library
  
  radio.begin();

  radio.setChannel(1);                 // Set RF channel to 1
  radio.setAutoAck(0);                 // Disable ACKnowledgement packets
  radio.setDataRate(RF_SPEED);         // Set data rate as specified in user options
  radio.setCRCLength(RF24_CRC_8);
  radio.openWritingPipe(pipes[0]);          // Set up reading and writing pipes
  radio.openReadingPipe(1,pipes[1]);
  radio.startListening();                   // Exit sending mode

  setup_wifi();
  client.setServer(mqtt_server, 1883);
  reconnect();

  esp_task_wdt_init(2,false);
 xTaskCreatePinnedToCore(
   onReceiveRadio,                  /* pvTaskCode */
   "Workload1",            /* pcName */
   1000,                   /* usStackDepth */
   NULL,                   /* pvParameters */
   1,                      /* uxPriority */
   &TaskA,                 /* pxCreatedTask */
   0);                     /* xCoreID */

}
void loop() {

  if (!client.connected()) {
    reconnect();
  }
  if(buffFull[whichBuff])
  {
    byte payload[bucketTotal*buffSize];
    int w=0;
    for(int x=0;x<bucketTotal;x++)
    {
      for(int y=0;y<buffSize;y++)
      {
        payload[w++] = buffer[whichBuff][x][y];
      }
    }
    client.publish("/esp32/output",payload,bucketTotal*buffSize); // mqtt transmission
    
    buffFull[whichBuff] = false;
  }
}
```

When I run the full code this, I get the following watchdog errors:

```cpp
E (6608) task_wdt: Task watchdog got triggered. The following tasks did not reset the watchdog in time:
E (6608) task_wdt:  - IDLE0 (CPU 0)
E (6608) task_wdt: Tasks currently running:
E (6608) task_wdt: CPU 0: Workload1
E (6608) task_wdt: CPU 1: loopTask
E (6608) task_wdt: Aborting.
abort() was called at PC 0x400db86f on core 0
```

I was able to get rid of this error by putting in a `else { vTaskDelay(1); }` just after the first `if` statement in `onReceiveRadio` which I'll show below.  And although the code ran without errors, the problem is that the delay is undesirable since I need to receive the payload at a higher frequency.  So I then tried to get rid of my original problem by feeding the watchdog, but this gave me back the same errors I originally had.  Below is my entire code with the watchdog set up.

```cpp
#include <RF24.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <PubSubClient.h>
#include <esp_task_wdt.h>

// Replace the next variables with your SSID/Password combination
const char* ssid = "mynetwork";
const char* password = "mypass";
const char* mqtt_server = "192.168.0.29";

/***********************************************
//******* MANDATORY User Variables **************/

 // Maximum Range: Sample rate 16000, RF_SPEED RF24_250KBPS
 // Maximum Quality: Sample rate 44000, RF_SPEED RF24_2MBPS

#define SAMPLE_RATE 24000                     // The sample rate to use for transferring audio samples  Note: 44khz+ sample rate requires 8-bits per sample
#define RF_SPEED RF24_1MBPS                   // RF24_250KBPS will do 13-20khz+ sample rate, RF24_1MBPS up to 24-44khz+, RF24_2MBPS for higher. These are not limits, just a guide.

/***************** Optional/Advanced User Variables ******/

#define bucketTotal 3
#define buffSize 32                           // The size of the memory buffer to use. Not really configurable.


/*********  Automated pin selections, override by defining above  ************/

//********Radio Defines ****************************
// Radio pipe addresses for the 2 nodes to communicate.
const uint64_t pipes[14] = { 0xABCDABCD71LL, 0x544d52687CLL, 0x544d526832LL, 0x544d52683CLL,0x544d526846LL, 0x544d526850LL,0x544d52685ALL, 0x544d526820LL, 0x544d52686ELL, 0x544d52684BLL, 0x544d526841LL, 0x544d526855LL,0x544d52685FLL,0x544d526869LL};



/* BEGIN PROJECT */

volatile boolean buffFull[2] = {false,false}, whichBuff = false;
int loadBufferN=0, intCount = 0;
byte buffer[2][bucketTotal][buffSize+1];
TaskHandle_t TaskA;

RF24 radio(12,14);    // Set radio up using pins 7 (CE) 8 (CS)
WiFiClient espClient;
PubSubClient client(espClient);

void onTimer(void * param) {

  esp_task_wdt_add(nullptr);
  while(1)
  {    
    bool n = !whichBuff;
    if(!buffFull[n] && radio.available() )
    {   
      radio.read(&buffer[n][loadBufferN],buffSize);         // Read the payload from the radio
      loadBufferN++;
    }
    else
    {
      //vTaskDelay(1);
      delayMicroseconds(50); // Maybe delaying things help a bit?
      esp_task_wdt_reset();
    }
    if(loadBufferN >= bucketTotal)
    {
      loadBufferN = 0;
      buffFull[n] = true;
      whichBuff = n;
    }
  }
}

void setup_wifi() {
  delay(10);
  // We start by connecting to a WiFi network
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }

  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");
  Serial.println("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
}

void reconnect() {
  // Loop until we're reconnected
  while (!client.connected()) {
    Serial.print("Attempting MQTT connection...");
    // Attempt to connect
    if (client.connect("ESP8266Client")) {
      Serial.println("connected");
      // Subscribe
      //client.subscribe("esp32/output");
    } else {
      Serial.print("failed, rc=");
      Serial.print(client.state());
      Serial.println(" try again in 5 seconds");
      // Wait 5 seconds before retrying
      delay(5000);
    }
  }
}

void setup() {      
  Serial.begin(115200);   // Enable Arduino serial library
  
  radio.begin();

  radio.setChannel(1);                 // Set RF channel to 1
  radio.setAutoAck(0);                 // Disable ACKnowledgement packets
  radio.setDataRate(RF_SPEED);         // Set data rate as specified in user options
  radio.setCRCLength(RF24_CRC_8);
  radio.openWritingPipe(pipes[0]);          // Set up reading and writing pipes
  radio.openReadingPipe(1,pipes[1]);
  radio.startListening();                   // Exit sending mode

  setup_wifi();
  client.setServer(mqtt_server, 1883);
  reconnect();

  esp_task_wdt_init(2,false);
 xTaskCreatePinnedToCore(
   onTimer,                  /* pvTaskCode */
   "Workload1",            /* pcName */
   1000,                   /* usStackDepth */
   NULL,                   /* pvParameters */
   1,                      /* uxPriority */
   &TaskA,                 /* pxCreatedTask */
   0);                     /* xCoreID */

}

void loop() {

  if (!client.connected()) {
    reconnect();
  }
  if(buffFull[whichBuff])
  {
    byte payload[bucketTotal*buffSize];
    int w=0;
    for(int x=0;x<bucketTotal;x++)
    {
      for(int y=0;y<buffSize;y++)
      {
        payload[w++] = buffer[whichBuff][x][y];
      }
    }
    client.publish("/esp32/output",payload,bucketTotal*buffSize); // mqtt transmission
    
    buffFull[whichBuff] = false;
  }
}
```

So my question is how can I go about relaying the stream of information from NRF24L01 over to the MQTT broker without these watchdog issues?

**UPDATE**

I don't know if this is really a long term/durable solution since I haven't fully tested it, but I got the errors to subside by changing

```cpp
esp_task_wdt_init(2,false);
```

to

```cpp
esp_task_wdt_init(999,false);
```

My onReceiveRadio is like this now:

```cpp
void onReceiveRadio(void * param) {

  esp_task_wdt_add(nullptr);
  while(1)
  {    
    bool n = !whichBuff;
    if(!buffFull[n] && radio.available() )
    {   
      radio.read(&buffer[n][loadBufferN],buffSize);         // Read the payload from the radio
      loadBufferN++;
    }

    esp_task_wdt_reset();
    
    if(loadBufferN >= bucketTotal)
    {
      loadBufferN = 0;
      buffFull[n] = true;
      whichBuff = n;
    }
  }
}
```

So essentially, I told the watch dog to wait as long as `999` seconds to be fed.

Comment: In light of the update, what exactly is your question?  If the update is actually the answer to your question, please [edit] the question to remove the update and post it in an answer instead.  Thanks!

Comment: your watchdog is getting triggered ..... why do you call it `watchdog error`? .... it is doing what it is supposed to do